# Simple_Fields_For: Multiple Blank Lines on a Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, fields-for

I am trying to get a number of blank lines on a simple form using simple_fields_for but only one line/record displays. This is the code below, the models, controller, and view.

```
class Journal < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :journal_lines
end

class JournalLine < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :journal
end


class JournalController < ApplicationController
    def  new
        @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:organisation_id])
        @journal = Journal.new
        @journal.journal_lines = Array.new(5, JournalLine.new)
    end
...


<%= simple_form_for @journal, :url => {:controller => 'journal', :action => 'create', :id => @organisation.id}, :method => :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :transaction_date, as: :string, input_html: {class: 'datepicker'} %>
    <%= f.input :reference %>
    <%= f.input :memo %>

    <table>
        <tr><td>Account</td><td>Debit</td><td>Credit</td><td>Memo</td></tr>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :journal_lines do |jl| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= jl.input :finacct_id, :collection => Finacct.all, :label_method => :full_account_name, :value_method => :id, :label => false ,:include_blank => false %></td>
                <td><%= jl.input :debit, :label => false %></td>
                <td><%= jl.input :credit, :label => false %></td>
                <td><%= jl.input :memo, :label => false %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
    <%= submit_tag 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure why I cannot see more than one journal line on the screen. When I log the journal_lines object I see 5 empty objects, but only one displays in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I did get an answer but it didn't work as answered so the poster deleted it. However, after a lot of messing around it turned out to be the journal model needed the following

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :journal_lines
```

Once I added that, all five blank lines showed up on the form.

The other answer also suggested that I do this in the controller

```
    @journal = Journal.new
    5.times do |i|
        @journal.journal_lines.build
    end
```

Not sure if that made a difference, but it's in now. Hope this helps.